# Does a va_list have to be the last argument in a function declaration?

Tags: c

Seemingly simple question, but haven't been able to find an answer on SO or in the C standard. Question is whether a `va_list` must be the last parameter to a function in C (presuming, of course, the function takes a `va_list` as a parameter).

For example, is this safe?

```
int f(int a, char *b, va_list args, char *c);
```

or does it have to be the following

```
int f(int a, char *b, char *c, va_list args);
```

Comment: You might consider searching for how to find the last argument in a va_list.

Comment: `va_list` is an object type and can be used like any other - that's it, it doesn't matter the order it is coming among the other arguments in the arguments list.

Comment: @user3386109 - point taken.  Will delete that comment.  (I have no experience using `vprintf()`, so totally missed that usage.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing special about the `va_list` type in regard to its use as a parameter to a function, as its inclusion does not make it a variadic function.  Both examples are valid.

An actual variadic function must have at least one named argument and `...` at the end, and it needs to use `va_start` and `va_end` to set a `va_list` to read the variadic arguments .

Section 7.16p3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) describes the `va_list` type:

> The type declared is
>
> ```
> va_list
> ```
>
> which  is  a  complete  object  type  suitable  for  holding
> information  needed  by  the  macros `va_start`, `va_arg`, `va_end`,
> and `va_copy`.  If  access  to  the  varying  arguments  is desired,
> the  called  function  shall  declare  an  object  (generally
> referred  to  as `ap` in  this subclause)  having  type `va_list`.
> The  object `ap` may  be  passed  as  an  argument  to another
> function;  if  that  function  invokes  the `va_arg` macro  with
> parameter `ap`,  the value  of `ap` in  the  calling  function  is
> indeterminate  and  shall  be  passed  to  the `va_end` macro prior to
> any further reference to `ap`. <sup>253)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> 253. It  is  permitted  to  create  a  pointer  to  a `va_list` and
>      pass  that  pointer  to  another  function,  in  which case the
>      original function may make further use of the original list after the
>      other function returns.

As described here, a `va_list` or a pointer to a `va_list` may be passed to a function, and there is no mention of restricting it to the last argument.